# Error enumerating users in LDAP

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

I am getting the following error when trying to enumerate users in LDAP(Lightweight Directory Access Protocol). I have verified my connection string to the server (LDAP://domainname). The server is of course online and operational.

**Error Message**: Server is not operational
**Stack Trace**

```
[2264] System.Transactions Critical: 0 : 
[2264] <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>DefaultDomain</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The server is not operational. 
[2264] </Message><StackTrace> 
[2264] Server stack trace:  
[2264]    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) 
[2264]    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() 
[2264]    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() 
[2264]    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
```

**Update - added code**

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry =  new DirectoryEntry( "_LDAP://DOMAINNAME", "userName", "password" );
System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher( dirEntry );
        try
        {
            foreach ( SearchResult resEnt in dirSearcher.FindAll( ) )
            {
                DirectoryEntry de=resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry( );
                foreach ( string propname in de.Properties.PropertyNames )
                {
                    //Add to the datatable
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex1 )
        {
            //Log exception
        }
        finally
        {
            dirEntry.Dispose( );
            dirSearcher.Dispose( );
        }
```

Any thoughts on why this expection could occur would be much appreciated?

Thanks in advance,
Bharath K

Comment: Can you show us your code used to enumerate the users? What LDAP path are you using??

Comment: Have added the code to enumerate users. Have also verified that the server exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the reason for this was that I was using the domain short name instead of full name. The right format is

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry =  new DirectoryEntry( "LDAP://DOMAINFULLNAME", "userName", "password" );
```